# how i can find the time complexity of the above code

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, nested-loops

```
 for(i=0; i<n; i++) // time complexity n+1
{
    k=1;   // time complexity n
    while(k<=n) // time complexity n*(n+1)
    {
    for(j=0; j<k; j++) // time complexity ??
     printf("the sum of %d and %d is: %d\n",j,k,j+k); time complexity ??
    k++;
}
```

What is the time complexity of the above code? I stuck in the second (for) and i don't know how to find the time complexity because j is less than k and not less than n.

I always having problems related to time complexity, do you guys got some good article on it?
especially about the step count and loops.

Comment: complexity in which case, best, worst, etc?

Comment: @WaqasShabbir How is that relevant ? As far as I can see, the only input is `n`.

Comment: the worst complexity.i know the the only input is n but in the second for depends on k an not in n .

Comment: it'll be `n*n*n`, the last loop is also related to `n` via `k`

Answer (score 3):

From the question :

> because j is less than k and not less than n.

This is just plain wrong, and I guess that's the assumption that got you stuck. We know what values k can take. In your code, it ranges from 1 to n (included). Thus, if j is less than k, it is also less than n.

From the comments :

> i know the the only input is n but in the second for depends on k an not in n .

If a variable depends on anything, it's on the input. `j` depends on `k` that itself depends on `n`, which means `j` depends on `n`.

However, this is not enough to deduce the complexity. In the end, what you need to know is how many times `printf` is called.

The outer for loop is executed n times no matter what. We can factor this out.

The number of executions of the inner for loop depends on k, which is modified within the while loop. We know k takes every value from 1 to n exactly once. That means the inner for loop will first be executed once, then twice, then three times and so on, up until n times.

Thus, discarding the outer for loop, `printf` is called `1+2+3+...+n` times. That sum is very well known and easy to calculate : `1+2+3+...+n = n*(n+1)/2 = (n^2 + n)/2`.

Finally, the total number of calls to `printf` is `n * (n^2 + n)/2 = n^3/2 + n^2/2 = O(n^3)`. That's your time complexity.

A final note about this kind of codes. Once you see the same patterns a few times, you quickly start to recognize the kind of complexity involved. Then, when you see that kind of nested loops with dependent variables, you immediately know that the complexity for each loop is linear.

For instance, in the following, `f` is called `n*(n+1)*(n+2)/6 = O(n^3)` times.

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
    for (j = 1; j <= i; ++j) {
        for (k = 1; k <= j; ++k) {
             f();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, simplify the code to show the main loops. So, we have a structure of:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for(int k = 1; k <= n; k++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
        }
    }
}
```

The outer-loops run `n * n` times but there's not much you can do with this information because the complexity of the inner-loop changes based on which iteration of the outer-loop you're on, so it's not as simple as calculating the number of times the outer loops run and multiplying by some other value.

Instead, I would find it easier to start with the inner-loop, and then add the outer-loops from the inner-most to outer-most.

- The complexity of the inner-most loop is `k`.
- With the middle loop, it's the sum of `k` (the complexity above) where `k = 1 to n`. So `1 + 2 + ... + n = (n^2 + n) / 2`.
- With the outer loop, it's done `n` times so another multiplication by `n`. So `n * (n^2 + n) / 2`.

After simplifying, we get a total of `O(n^3)`

Comment: I don't know how you got the average number of times the inner loop runs, but it's not `(n^2 + n) / (2n + 2)`, it's just `(n+1)/2`. Which is kinda weird considering you get the correct result at the end. Also, the second (middle) loop doesn't run `n * (n + 1)` times, just `n*n` times.

Comment: @Nelxiost I added that in later based on dividing the total by `n(n + 1)`, but I got the loop bounds wrong. By using `n^2` instead, it's `(n^2 + n) / 2n` = `(n + 1) / 2` like you said.

Answer (score -1):

The time complexity for the above code is : n x n x n = n^3 + 1+ 1 = n^3 + 2 for the 3 loops plus the two constants. Since n^3 carries the heaviest growing rate the constant values can be ignored, so the Time complexity would be n^3.

Note: Take each loop as (n) and to obtained the total time, multiple the (n) values in each loop.

Hope this will help !

Comment: The time complexity is far from `n^3 + 2`, even though it's `O(n^3)`. Also, this doesn't explain why you would take the innermost loop complexity as `O(n)`.

Comment: "Take each loop as (n)" ?? Why?? Please explain. The innermost loop depends on k. Your answer is correct. Please explain the reasoning behind the answer correctly....

Comment: @User_Targaryen. I stated my explanation clearly above, If you think it is not right or not complete, please come up with a better one. The person who posted this question definitely need help from people like you.

Comment: From where do you get n, when the innermost loop depends on k?? If you consider the 2 most inner loops together, you will find that it runs 1 + 2 + 3 + .... + n times = n(n+1)/2 for the 2 inner loops and n for the outermost loop. Multiplying all, we get `O(n^3)`.

Comment: @User_Targaryen . Thanks for the enlightenment. This is the detail explanation of what I was saying.